# Parse list of dictionaries in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I need to search for key `name` in the below list of dictionaries in a list and need to get value for `uuid` for that particular dictionary

```
body = '''{
   "operatingsystems":[
      {
         "uuid":"2baae445-eec5-41c4-a373-05f0125d4dc0",
         "name":"my node",
         "description":"my node is compute node",
         "status":"",
         "provision_capabilities":[
            "controller"
         ],
         "hostname":"9.37.75.49",
         "os_name":"Linux",
         "os_type":"RHEL",
         "version":"6.5",
         "architecture":"x86_64",
         "is_hypervisor":"false",
         "hypervisor_type":null,
         "hypervisor_id":null,
         "total_memory":16334340,
         "processor_speed":null,
         "processor_num_cores":null,
         "max_storage":"",
         "links":[
            {
               "href":"/v1/5e9dc1e2a6864739b278f0b67e6229c6/operatingsystems/2baae445-eec5-41c4-a373-05f0125d4dc0",
               "rel":"self"
            },
            {
               "href":"5e9dc1e2a6864739b278f0b67e6229c6/operatingsystems/2baae445-eec5-41c4-a373-05f0125d4dc0",
               "rel":"bookmark"
            }
         ],
         "created":"2014-04-16T05:44:04.327626",
         "updated":"2014-04-16T06:45:58.181892"
      },
      {
         "uuid":"0fcc39c1-1956-41b9-97c8-8462edbb8a46",
         "name":"OpsMgmt node3",
         "description":"Operating system for pool3",
         "status":"",
         "provision_capabilities":[
            "sdnve_controller"
         ],
         "hostname":"9.37.75.121",
         "os_name":"Linux",
         "os_type":"RHEL",
         "version":"6.5",
         "architecture":"x86_64",
         "is_hypervisor":false,
         "hypervisor_type":null,
         "hypervisor_id":null,
         "total_memory":3923764,
         "processor_speed":null,
         "processor_num_cores":null,
         "max_storage":"",
         "links":[
            {
               "href":"/v1/5e9dc1e2a6864739b278f0b67e6229c6/operatingsystems/0fcc39c1-1956-41b9-97c8-8462edbb8a46",
               "rel":"self"
            },
            {
               "href":"5e9dc1e2a6864739b278f0b67e6229c6/operatingsystems/0fcc39c1-1956-41b9-97c8-8462edbb8a46",
               "rel":"bookmark"
            }
         ],
         "created":"2014-04-16T05:44:04.452042",
         "updated":null
      },
      {
         "uuid":"1d15250f-ec0b-42e9-9e61-4da92024e024",
         "name":"OpsMgmt node",
         "description":"Operating system for pool",
         "status":"",
         "provision_capabilities":[
            "compute"
         ],
         "hostname":"9.37.88.253",
         "os_name":"Linux",
         "os_type":"RHEL",
         "version":"6.5",
         "architecture":"x86_64",
         "is_hypervisor":false,
         "hypervisor_type":null,
         "hypervisor_id":null,
         "total_memory":8030692,
         "processor_speed":null,
         "processor_num_cores":null,
         "max_storage":"",
         "links":[
            {
               "href":"/v1/5e9dc1e2a6864739b278f0b67e6229c6/operatingsystems/1d15250f-ec0b-42e9-9e61-4da92024e024",
               "rel":"self"
            },
            {
               "href":"5e9dc1e2a6864739b278f0b67e6229c6/operatingsystems/1d15250f-ec0b-42e9-9e61-4da92024e024",
               "rel":"bookmark"
            }
         ],
         "created":"2014-04-16T06:22:36.261333",
         "updated":null
      },
      {
         "uuid":"315efdbd-9537-4b32-8675-63cff8b2f9b2",
         "name":"OpsMgmt node itself",
         "description":"Operating system for pool which is same as opsmanagement",
         "status":"",
         "provision_capabilities":[
            "connectivity"
         ],
         "hostname":"9.37.75.129",
         "os_name":"Linux",
         "os_type":"RHEL",
         "version":"6.5",
         "architecture":"x86_64",
         "is_hypervisor":false,
         "hypervisor_type":null,
         "hypervisor_id":null,
         "total_memory":65977136,
         "processor_speed":null,
         "processor_num_cores":null,
         "max_storage":"",
         "links":[
            {
               "href":"/v1/5e9dc1e2a6864739b278f0b67e6229c6/operatingsystems/315efdbd-9537-4b32-8675-63cff8b2f9b2",
               "rel":"self"
            },
            {
               "href":"5e9dc1e2a6864739b278f0b67e6229c6/operatingsystems/315efdbd-9537-4b32-8675-63cff8b2f9b2",
               "rel":"bookmark"
            }
         ],
         "created":"2014-04-16T07:11:56.258874",
         "updated":null
      },
      {
         "uuid":"5c907a69-0ad0-4a81-b64b-6c2b281004d6",
         "name":"compute node",
         "description":"Operating system for Compute",
         "status":"",
         "provision_capabilities":[
            "compute"
         ],
         "hostname":"9.37.89.12",
         "os_name":"Linux",
         "os_type":"RHEL",
         "version":"6.5",
         "architecture":"x86_64",
         "is_hypervisor":false,
         "hypervisor_type":null,
         "hypervisor_id":null,
         "total_memory":32850352,
         "processor_speed":null,
         "processor_num_cores":null,
         "max_storage":"",
         "links":[
            {
               "href":"/v1/5e9dc1e2a6864739b278f0b67e6229c6/operatingsystems/5c907a69-0ad0-4a81-b64b-6c2b281004d6",
               "rel":"self"
            },
            {
               "href":"5e9dc1e2a6864739b278f0b67e6229c6/operatingsystems/5c907a69-0ad0-4a81-b64b-6c2b281004d6",
               "rel":"bookmark"
            }
         ],
         "created":"2014-04-17T09:08:17.967685",
         "updated":null
      }
   ]
}'''
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. We help with bugs.. not doing your job

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework dump type of question.

Comment: @ErikAllik That's harsh, it's not that bad.

Comment: @ErikAllik: it may be lacking in a little effort, but it is not a homemork dump either.

Comment: He's asking others to do all the work for him; hence "homework style"; what part of it does not fit that criterion? He didn't even other to format the JSON and just pasted a huge one-line string.

Comment: @ErikAllik: Most likely because they have no idea it **is** JSON in the first place? It's wonderful easy once you know all these things, you forget what it is like when you are still at the start.

Comment: This argument is quite arbitrary; questions like this are viewed as homework-style all the time and closed.

Answer (score 2):

You have JSON data; use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse it. From there on out you can access the `operatingssystems` list and search for a given name:

```
import json

data = json.loads(body)
name_to_find = 'foobar'
uuid = next((d['uuid']
             for d in data['operatingsystems'] 
             if d['name'] == name_to_find), None)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = json.loads(body)
>>> name_to_find = 'OpsMgmt node'
>>> next((d['uuid']
...              for d in data['operatingsystems'] 
...              if d['name'] == name_to_find), None)
u'1d15250f-ec0b-42e9-9e61-4da92024e024'
```

Answer (score 0):

This tool may help you with that. It's an online JSON viewer that I find very useful. Copy just the JSON part of this text to the viewer.

[Online JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

But next time, consider organizing your question better.